# New sign ups with no orders report

Tags: magento-1.8, reports

How would I run a report to see all the new signups which havent placed any orders yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break this question in two parts to make it simple:

> 1. How to create a custom report in Magento?

There are too many forums and questions in SE to answer this. The best one I can see now is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030255/how-to-create-a-report-in-magento/7032477#7032477

---

> 2. How to find customers who have not placed any order?

```
$targetCustomers = array();

$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();

foreach ($collection as $user){
 $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$user->getId());
    if($orders->getSize() == 0){
        $targetCustomers[] = $user->getId();
    } 

}
```

and additionally you may also want to filter customers who have registered after #specificdate# for the **New signups**